# Powershell - Log Off Script to copy two files

Tags: powershell

Very much new to Powershell scripting.  Usually am running scripts I find somewhere else...not trying to create my own.  I am using Remote Desktop Services.  I have a batch file that will copy two directories to a userpath on log on.  When the user logs out, I only want to copy 2 specific files back to the file share.  Here is the powershell script I (along with help from another online community) came up with.

I would like to assign this to a Log Off Script for the users.  It fails at $unc.  More information:
W drive points to the users directory on the File Share.
I have also tried to path it as \\fileshare\Share\$username

CODE:

```
function copydir ($user){

$userpath = $env:HOMEPATH
$unc = W:
copy-item $userpath\Data\App\DMS\DMS.accde $user\Data\App\DMS\ -recurse
copy-item $userpath\Dynamics\GP2010\dex.ini $user\Dynamics\GP2010\ -recurse
}
$username = $env:username
copydir $username*
```

Error:
The term \\fileshare\Share\$username is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file....

So, obviously it doesn't like the $UNC parameter.  I tried to run it with just W: instead since that points to the User Profile on File Server and get a similar error.

But the basic premise I'm trying to accomplish is to copy Data\App\DMS\DMS.accde and Dynamics\GP2010\dex.ini to a users roaming profile on a file share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that you need to have the double slashes at the front for your UNC path?

```
$unc = "\\fileshare\Share\$user"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did have it, that is just a typo.  I will edit the post!  Good catch, that would definitely have caused an issue.  It appears to not like any part of the UNC line.  I'm not sure if it's even needed, but am not sure what else I could put.

Comment: Actually I just went to edit th epost and it shows double slashes.  Not sure why it's displaying as a single.

Comment: Could it be that you need to use `$user` instead of `$username` because you are using it inside of the function?